# What does negative top and left mean in D2D1_RECT_F returned from GetImageLocalBounds?

Tags: c++, direct2d

I'm struggling getting the size of the result of gaussian blur `ID2D1Effect` (`CLSID_D2D1GaussianBlur`).

I want to draw a shadow box behind a rectangle where the shadow will be positioned such that the rectangle is in the center of the shadow.

I start by creating an `IWICBitmap` with the size of the rectangle in DIPs like this:

```
ComPtr<IWICBitmap> bitmap;
HRESULT hr = wic_factory_->CreateBitmap(size.w, size.h, convert_format(ImageFormat::argb32_premultiplied),
        WICBitmapCacheOnDemand, &bitmap);
```

Then I fill this bitmap with black (or the shadow color) and make `ID2D1Bitmap` from it:

```
ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> shadow_bitmap;
HRESULT hr = render_target_->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(wic_bitmap.Get(), &shadow_bitmap);
```

I verify that the size of bitmap in DIPs returned from `shadow_bitmap->GetSize()` almost equals the size of the rectangle (due to float ceiling when creating the wic bitmap)

After that I create the effect and apply it:

```
ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> blur_effect;
d2d_context_->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1GaussianBlur, &blur_effect);
blur_effect->SetInput(0, shadow_bitmap.Get());
blur_effect->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION, shadow_opts.width * 3);
blur_effect->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_OPTIMIZATION, D2D1_DIRECTIONALBLUR_OPTIMIZATION_QUALITY);
```

Microsoft docs say that the blur radius (width increase of shadow) is the deviation (in DIPs) multiplied by 3 hence I'm doing so.

Then I get the output and get the local bounds in DIPs (the transform of the target will be applied when drawing the image)

```
ComPtr<ID2D1Image> out_img;
blur_effect->GetOutput(&out_img);
D2D1_RECT_F img_rect{};
d2d_context_->GetImageLocalBounds(out_img.Get(), &img_rect);
```

Thing I didn't expect start from here:

- The top and left of the out image is negative! I didn't expect an image will have a top left offset (just like bitmaps don't)
- I don't know the width of the image: is it the `img_rect.right` or `img_rect.right - img_rect.left`?
- The same thing for the height of the out image
- I tried calculating the width and height of the image in both methods but they don't seem to match the visible dimensions of the shadow
- The width and height from the previous methods didn't result in the growth documented:

> Output bitmap growth (X and Y) = StandardDeviation (DIPs)*6*((User DPI)/96)

Also, the document is unclear (or I didn't understand well) is this growth in pixels or DIPs?

Due to the above I'm having trouble positioning the shadow so the rectangle is in its center

Comment: We have no idea of any size in that code... My guess would be that the negative values are because the effect is applied all around original rectangle.

Comment: @Phil1970 I mean the size and offsets of `img_rect` resulted from `GetImageLocalBounds`

Comment: D2D1_RECT_F is not a "bounds" type, it's an array of 4 signed floats that can serve many purposes. Having negative values just means the effect uses a bigger texture to build its effect, which seems logical for blur. And I can reproduce https://github.com/smourier/WicNet/blob/main/WicNet.Tests/Program.cs#L368 (this is C# but it's exactly the same type of code, and bounds.left/top is negative)

Comment: @SimonMourier what I have observed so far: the width and height of the result image is the right and bottom fields of `D2D1_RECT_F` respectively

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems to have got it now!
The `GetImageLocalBounds` outputs a rectangle whose fields are interpreted as follows:

- The width of the image is `right` field
- The height of the image is `bottom` field
- The `top` field equals the total vertical increase (if negative) or decrease (if positive) from input images to output image. Note this is the total in both top and bottom
- Similarly the `left` field equals the total horizontal increase or decrease

In case of blur effect the horizontal increase is the same in each side and equals `left / 2`. The same for vertical increase also.

When you pass the image to `DrawImage` and pass an offset of `(0, 0)` the output image' top left point will not be drawn at `(0, 0)` but instead at `(left, top)` of its bound rectangle.

There is still another thing about direct2d bluring I didn't manage to do it: control the growth of the image.